# How to store image using nodejs,express,mongodb and react

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, react-native

I'm trying to store an image using node and mongodb.I'm using react in frontend.I tried using multer but it gives error saying "TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer".Is there any other way to store image using node and mongodb

```
 //server.js

 const multer = require("multer");

 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: function (req, res, cb) {
         cb(null, 'uploads/')
      }
 });

 const upload = multer({
     storage: storage
 });

 router.route('/imageCard/add').post(upload.single('file'), function                     (req, res) 
 {
     let imageDetails=new ImageCard();
     imageDetails.name=req.body.name;
     imageDetails.imgSource= fs.readFileSync(req.body.imgSource);
     imageDetails.price=req.body.price;
     imageDetails.size=req.body.size;
     imageDetails.save().then(details=>
      {
          res.status(200).json('Added');
      }).catch(err=>{
     result.status(400).send('Failed to Add');
     })

 });

 //(model )
 import mongoose from 'mongoose';
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 let imageCard=new Schema({

     name:{
         type:String
     },
     imgSource:{

         type:Buffer
     },
     size:{
         type:String
     },
     price:{
         type:String
     }
 });

 export default mongoose.model('ImageCard', imageCard);

 //react file
 onChange(e) {   
    this.state.file = e.target.files[0];  
 }

 onsubmit() {
    console.log('on submit');
    const newDoc = {
        name: document.getElementById('name').value,
        price: document.getElementById('price').value,
        size: document.getElementById('size').value,

        imgSource:this.state.file
    }
    console.log(newDoc.imgSource);
              axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/imageCard/add`,newDoc).then(res=>{
        console.log(res.data);
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    });

}
```

If I use Below code then it gives this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

```
imageDetails.imgSource= fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
```

I am not receiving imgSource values in server.js file ,it shows null values.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem just a few days ago.
Finally I achive it by doing this:

```
    const multer  = require('multer');
const path = require('path');


const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, callback) => {
            try {
                let path = "What ever your path is";
                fs.mkdirsSync(path);
                callback(null, path);
            }catch (e) {
                callback(jsonError(e),null)
            }
        },
        filename: (req, file, callback) => {
            //original name is the uploaded file's name with ext
            callback(null, mongoose.Types.ObjectId()+path.extname(file.originalname));
        }
    })
});
```

Then in your route make your uoload.whatever.
Notice than once multer works you will have a new req.file or req.files with name, size etc